# How to change destination for folder received with GET. Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ftp

I am currently grabbing a file using GET in ftp and would like to figure a way to pick the destination folder that it goes after I get it.

It is now just going to the home folder in the host server and I would like to get it to go to a folder called `temp`. Would I change to the temp folder before I enter ftp on the host server? Here is what I have code wise:

```
sftp $2@$3 <<EOM
    cd $OUTBOUND
    get test.log
    bye
EOM
```

As of right now everything works correctly but the file is getting sent just to the home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lcd $HOME/temp` inside your `sftp` commands to make sure received file goes there:

```
sftp $2@$3 <<EOM
    lcd $HOME/temp
    cd $OUTBOUND
    get test.log
    bye
EOM
```